# posting a footer contact form to a different script not working

Tags: wordpress

I have two files   the one which hosts my actual contact form and then a file where i post the form to.

contactform.php (which is part of the footer template)

```
<form id="contact" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sendmail.php" method="post">    
   <label for="name">Your name: *</label>
   <input type="text" id="nameinput" name="name" value=""/>

   <label for="email">Your email: *</label>
   <input type="text" id="emailinput" name="email" value=""/>

   <label for="comment">Your message: *</label>
   <textarea cols="20" rows="7" id="commentinput" name="comment"> </textarea><br />
</form>
```

sendmail.php

```
<?PHP 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      error_reporting(E_NOTICE);
      function valid_email($str)
      {
        return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
      }

      if($_POST['name']!='' && $_POST['email']!='' && valid_email($_POST['email'])==TRUE && strlen($_POST['comment'])>1)
      {

          $to = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", hexstr($_POST['receiver']));
          $from = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $_POST['email']);
          $subject = "Website contact message from ".$_POST['name'];
          $message = $_POST['comment'];

          $match = "/(bcc:|cc:|content\-type:)/i";
            if (preg_match($match, $to) ||
                preg_match($match, $from) ||
                preg_match($match, $message)) {
              die("Header injection detected.");
            }
          $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
          $headers .= "Reply-to: ".$from."\r\n";

    if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,'',true))
          {
              echo 1; //SUCCESS
          }
          else {
              echo 2; //FAILURE - server failure
          }
      }
      else {
      echo 3; //FAILURE - not valid email

      }
      }else{

         die("Direct access not allowed!");
       }

        function hexstr($hexstr) {
              $hexstr = str_replace(' ', '', $hexstr);
              $hexstr = str_replace('\x', '', $hexstr);
              $retstr = pack('H*', $hexstr);
              return $retstr;
            }

  ?>
```

The issue is that this does not know of wp_mail function.  I know that I need to include something so wp_mail will be available but what do I add?  The function does exist.  The issue with including the file that has wp_mail defined is that inside that function it requires some core php functions (wp_mail is being overwritten by cimy_swift plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi why not try just submitting the form to the base wpurl? then within your header.php file copy and paste your code in?

ie: using a hidden field you can check to see if its been posts, in this case the hidden field is called 'action' and it has a value of 'sendemail'.

**form**

```
<form id="contact" action="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>" method="post"> 
//form stuff
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendemail" />
</form>
```

**Header.php**
within the header file we do a call to check and see if the form has been posted,

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php wp_title();?></title>
<?php 
if( isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']=='sendemail')  ) {
// run your code

}
?>
</head>
```

if you dont want to go down that route, and wish to use your theme folder to hold the php script then what to is, include the below in your sendmail.php file

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE);
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
//above is assuming your file is located in the theme root, not a sub folder.
```

this will give you access to all the wordpress functions and shortcodes etc..etc..
hope that helps a little..

Marty

Comment: Thank you for that.  I will try this when I get back on my development system and let you know if it worked.

Comment: This still does not work.. putting or using any function "halts" the script. There is no error displaying either